# Как узнать характеристики дисплея и протокол управления

Tags: display

Был у меня сломанный планшет, разобрал, достал дисплей. Планшет - китайский, неизвестного производителя (в коробке нашёл только инструкцию по использованию, в ней не было ни слова о производителе).
К самому дисплею с задней стороны прикреплена плата (возможно, интерфейс или драйвер). На дисплее, плате и шине от дисплея стоит код - начинается с `AR101H03N-`, далее у экрана `BL` , у платы `PCB` , у шины `FPC`, и в конце `-V1`.
Также на задней части дисплея есть код `AR101H03N20111110GF`.

Фото:

[image: Задняя часть дисплея]

Плата:

[image: Плата на задней части дисплея]

Разъём справа использовался для соединения с главной платой планшета.

Чип-драйвер для дисплея(он на главной плате планшета) - THine 104LT 1HC63LVDM83D
Похоже, LVDM - многоточечный LVDS
Нужно знать как "общаться" с экраном.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Контакты в левом нижнем углу платы подписаны под LVDS. Дороги идут к CN1, в нем 40 контактов. Вероятно там 40-контактный LVDS. Может даже какая-то "стандартная" распиновка.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: Протокол стандартный 6-бит на цвет. Назначение выводов - хорошо прослеживается по-дорожкам и надписям там где 30pin вход и 40 пин вход. Данный разьём позволяет подключить матрицу к ноутам 2000-х годов, где шина не разделена на чётную и нечетную. Или к старым материнкам от asus и intel с 30-пиновым LVDS выходом. Детали протокола можно найти по запросу LVDS. rx0+/- red, rx1+- green rx2+- blue, clk - clock. Если вопрос всё ещё актуален - маякните - я вам нагуглю datasheet или... можете найти самостоятельно по фразе "G156 datasheet" в pdf-ках.

Comment: http://comsystem-tlt.ru/obzori/raspinovka-hodovih-matric-lvds-i-edp вот и разпиновка